# Match Strings, not preceded by a-z or A-Z, and which contains 1324

Tags: regex

Using regex, I want to match strings in a text if:

1. They contain `1324` as a substring
2. The `1324` substring is not preceded by one or more characters like `a-zA-Z`

For instance:

- '`1324test`' should be matched
- '`1324`' should be matched
- '`test test :/1324test`' should be matched
- '`test test 1324test`' should be matched
- '`test test 1324`' should be matched
- '`test test test1324test`' should **NOT** be matched

Here's my attempt: `[^a-zA-Z]+1324`

How can I do this ?

Comment: In your second example you show `1234`... do you mean `1324`?

Comment: @l'L'l, yes, sorry, it is a typo, i fixed it.

Comment: What regexp language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this RegEx:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])1324
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/lO1zK0/1)</kbd>

It uses a **Negative Lookbehind** (here is a [nice site](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) explaining them). This means it will check behind the `1324` (lookbehind it) to see if there are any letters (`[a-zA-Z]`). If there are, it will fail.

[image: Demo]

Comment: Wow! only in 37 steps !

Answer (score 2):

Use negative lookbehind:

```
.*(?<![a-zA-Z])1324.*
```

Comment: Why `.*` ? why not to remove them ? I think they are adding extra steps, for instance why not as follows: https://regex101.com/r/cQ6yW2/6, which reduces around 100+ steps (44 steps compared to 251 steps) ?

Comment: Because your question explicitly states that you want the regex to match strings that **contain** 1324 as a substring (point no.1 of your requirements). The regex you provided only matches the 1324 part of the string, not the rest of it. My regex matches the whole string.

Comment: Aha, got it. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

If your regex flavor doesn't support negative look-behinds (e.g. JS) you could do it with

```
(^|[^a-zA-Z])1324
```

Match start of string **or** Non-Alpha Character.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. I think your second test case should be **1324** not 1234

```
([^a-zA-Z]+|^)1324
```

[Here is a test link](https://regex101.com/r/cQ6yW2/3)

**Update:** The plus link is not needed. It just ads overhead. The proper example should be this

```
([^a-zA-Z]|^)1324
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xzK9v3elzQj4Vq-B)

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo, I fixed it

Comment: Why do we need to add `+`, I think it can work without `+` ? for example https://regex101.com/r/kU4hG9/1 .. The introduction of `+` is adding around 40 extra steps.

Comment: Yes it can work without the plus sign and it just adds overhead. The regex only needs to check one character in front of the match. I realized that after I posted. Unfortunately I already posted and I thought it would be bad netiquette to change it now. I am still not changing it but I am updating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can match on what you **don't** want without capturing, then capture what you do want to, then examine the captured portion.

```
/[a-z]1324|(1324)|.*/i
```

In JavaScript, your match would be given by

```
!!input.match(regexp)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think this fails in case the provided text does not contain 1324, you can try `!!"test test test".match(/[a-z]1324|(1324)/i)[1]` ... In this answer you assumed that match will return a non empty array, what if empty array returned like in this example ?! An error will be thrown: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`